# Read the source code for the command flink run -m yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading Flink's latest source code forked from `master` branch of github.

I would like to read the code path for the following command, but I didn't find where the code starts to interact with YARN and submit an application to YARN.

`flink run -m yarn-cluster -yqu Q1 -yn 6 -c my.MyFlink./myflink.jar`

The code path is:

```
1. CliFrontend#main
2. CliFrontend#parseParameters
3. CliFrontend#run(The ACTION_NAME is run in my case)
4. CliFrontend#getPackagedProgram and CliFrontend#buildProgram
5. CliFrontend#executeProgram
6. ClientUtils.executeProgram
7. program.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution();
```

my.MyFlink's main method starts to run and the yarn cluster should have already been created,but I didn't where the code that starts to interact with YARN in the above code path

Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks I find the answer.

```
protected void executeProgram(final Configuration configuration, final PackagedProgram program) throws ProgramInvocationException {
    ClientUtils.executeProgram(new DefaultExecutorServiceLoader(), configuration, program, false, false);
}
```

The code path to interact with YARN resides in the `DefaultExecutorServiceLoader`, but this heavy/important operation hides in a parameter of `ClientUtils.executeProgram`, kind of bad code practice.